# Adding multiple "owner" dropdown fields to a user story

Tags: rally

Sure this has been asked (and answered) before but I havent had luck finding it in search.

Im trying to edit the User Story template to allow for multiple "owners" which filter by the owner drop down list.

Before you think im crazy, i'll give some context. We have setup a personalised Kanban flow for our user stories that goes like this:

Backlog > In Design > Ready For Dev > In Dev > Ready For Test > Test > Ready for Acceptance

What im trying to do is have an owner within each practise

For example:

Desinger : Person 1

Dev : Person 2

Test : Person 3

That way if the tester has a question, they know who the dev was who worked on it (at a glance) and can go speak to them. Also, if a tester has the right skillset for a certain story they can nominate themselves for it before it progresses through the states.

I want each of these three fields to be limited to a drop down from the current team members, similar to the "Owner" provided drop down. Search is leading me to believe what I need is an attribute drop down.. but im not sure how I do this when editing a generic template (User Story).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is not the functionality within Rally to be able to edit the User Story template to allow the selection of more than one Owner.

A possible workaround would be to use a custom field.  While there are drop-down custom fields  available you would have to populate this with the desired values and that would be a manual process that would be difficult to manage.

I would suggest that the developer working on the Story puts their name as the Owner.  I would then create a custom string field that can be used by the testers to enter their name for the nomination process of working on that Story.